# Pagination error after updating to backbonejs Latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, pagination

So i'm learning backbonejs, using nodecellar-rethinkdb example as practice

After Updating the Backbone.js and Underscore.js files to last version, i'm getting an error saying "page is not defined". same code works fine with Backbone.js 0.9.2. So i guess something was deprecated.

Here the code for the pagination file who is giving me the error:

```
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var wines = this.model.models;
        var len = wines.length;
        var startPos = (this.options.page - 1) * 8;
        var endPos = Math.min(startPos + 8, len);

        $(this.el).html('<ul class="thumbnails"></ul>');

        for (var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
            $('.thumbnails', this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model: wines[i]}).render().el);
        }

        $(this.el).append(new Paginator({model: this.model, page: this.options.page}).render().el);

        return this;
    }
});

window.WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "li",

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});
```

Can you please give me the reason why the code is not working with last version, and fix it to work with latest backbone.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  keeping reference to options yourself, I don't think new versions of backbone keeps it.

```
Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function (options) {
    //add this
    this.options = options; // or this.page = options.page and update render accordingly
    this.render();
},
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding both works:  `initialize: function (options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.page = options.page;
    this.render();
},`

Comment: But it's fine to use both options? or can i fix it to just use 1? cuz when i use just: this.page = options.page; i got an error saying options is not defined

Comment: @RocketFuel When you use second you need to update following line like `$(this.el).append(new Paginator({model: this.model, page: this.page}).render().el);` ideally you don't need to keep a reference to the entire options object as long as the view exists in memory, so just keeping `this.page` is enough